# Differing number of rows error in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

Am trying to build a simple Shiny app to calculate air quality index. Following is the code chunk for Shiny `ui`  -

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("slate"),
                
                # Page header
                headerPanel('Air Quality Index'),
                
                # Input values
                sidebarPanel(
                  HTML("<h3>Input Air Parameters</h3>"),
                  
                  selectInput("City", label = "Please Select the City:", 
                              choices = list("abc", "def" , "xyz"), 
                              selected = "abc"),
                  sliderInput("PM2.5", "PM2.5 Levels:",
                              min = 0, max = 1000,
                              value = 50),
                  sliderInput("PM10", "PM10 Levels:",
                              min = 0, max = 1000,
                              value = 90),
                  
                  actionButton("submitbutton", "Calculate AQI", class = "btn btn-primary")
                ),
                
                mainPanel(
                  tags$label(h3('Air Quality Index-')), # Status/Output Text Box
                  verbatimTextOutput('contents'),
                  tableOutput('tabledata') # Prediction results table
                  
                )
)
```

And the `server` code is -

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
        # Input Data
  datasetInput <-  reactive({
    df1 <- data.frame(
      Names= c("City", 
               "PM2.5",      
               "PM10"),       
               
      Values = as.character(c(input$City, 
                              input$PM2.5, 
                              input$PM10)), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
    
    AQI <- "AQI"
    df1 <- rbind(df1, AQI)
    input <- data.table::transpose(df1)
    
    write.table(input,"input.csv", sep=",", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
    
    test <- read.csv(paste("input", ".csv", sep=""), header = TRUE)
    
    Output <- data.frame(Prediction=predict(RandomForest_AQI_Model,test))
    print(Output)
    
  })
  
  # Status/Output Text Box
  output$contents <- renderPrint({
    if (input$submitbutton>0) { 
      isolate("Calculation complete.") 
    } else {
      return("Server is ready for calculation.")
    }
  })
  
  # Prediction results table
  output$tabledata <- renderTable({
    if (input$submitbutton>0) { 
      isolate(datasetInput()) 
    } 
  })
  
}
```

And here is the problem occurs, after running the app in RStudio the UI loads correctly. But, when I submit my inputs to perform calculation, it throws the error for differing row numbers.
I don't know what's going wrong in `data.frame` function in `server`
I am uploading question for the first time so if I made any mistake in posting please let me know.
Any help would be awesome
Thanks!

Comment: If I had to *guess* (which I do, because we don't have the literal error text nor `RandomForest_AQI_Model`), I suspect that this has nothing to do with `shiny`. If you run just that one `reactive` block line by line, my guess is that it'll work through `test <- read.csv(.)`, but fails ... perhaps `predict` doesn't return exactly what you want it to.

Comment: I agree with @r2evans. Take the inputs that are causing the error and move the server code to a separate script/session and apply the inputs manually into the code. Also, the reason for as to why you would use `write.table()` and `read.csv()` is completely lost on me.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I tried plugging in all values manually into data frame and it worked fine, also the random forest runs perfectly. But again when I tried to load complete app it gave me error. Ill try to put all the logs so you can get clear idea.

Comment: You call `data.frame(names=c('city',...),...)`, transpose it, write to a csv without column names, then read it back in. This is a broken workflow. Why not just `df1 <- data.frame(City=input$City, PM2.5=input$PM2.5, PM10=input$PM10, AQI="AQI")`, skip `write.table` and `read.csv`, an call `predict` directly? (The only utility I can see in any of that is if you want to preserve the most-recent inputs used as a CSV file ... but even then, your method for getting there is needlessly complex.)

Comment: Try removing the dot in column name; change `PM2.5` to `PM25` or `PM2_5` or something else.  Also, please note @Phil's comment above.  Why can't you use `input` datatable directly in `predict()`?

Comment: Hey! Solved the issue by removing `write.table` and `read.csv`